# How to create custom validation rule that only accepts specific numbers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

How to set custom validation rule that accept only **1.00, 1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 2.00, 2.25, 2.50, 2.75 and 3.00** in input text? The *grades* and *grades1* are my inputs. 
1.35 should be invalid (incase you're thinking the solution of divisible by 5) 
1.26 should be invalid

**FormRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'app_id' => 'nullable',
        'subjects.*' => 'required|string',
        'subjects1.*' => 'required|string',
        'school_year' => 'required',
        'grades.*' => ['required','numeric','lt:2.50'],
        'grades1.*' => 'required|lt:2.50',
        'units.*' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'units1.*' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'term' => 'required',
        'term1' => 'required',
        'total.*' => 'nullable',
        'total1.*' => 'nullable',
        'gwa_1st' => 'required|lte:1.75',
        'gwa_2nd' => 'required|lte:1.75',
        'year_level' => 'required|string',
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        'award_applied' => 'required|string',
        'course_id' => 'required|string'
    ];
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(AchieversAwardRequest $request)
{

    $data = $request->validated();
    $award = new StudentApplicants();

    $award->user_id = $data['user_id'];
    $award->school_year = $data['school_year'];
    $award->gwa_1st = $data['gwa_1st'];
    $award->gwa_2nd = $data['gwa_2nd'];
    $award->year_level = $data['year_level'];

    if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('uploads/', $filename);
        $award->image = $filename;
    }

    $award->award_applied = $data['award_applied'];
    $award->course_id = $data['course_id'];
    $award->save();
    $lastid = $award->id;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the [`in`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-in) validation rule, something like the following:

```
$acceptable = [1.00, 1.25, 1.5, 2.75, 3.00];

$validator = Validator::make(['numbers_field' => 2.75], [
    'numbers_field' => [Rule::in($acceptable)]
]);
```

**Update**

Add the rule to your `AchieversAwardRequest` custom `FormRequest` `rules()` method along with all your other rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'app_id' => 'nullable',
        'subjects.*' => 'required|string',
        'subjects1.*' => 'required|string',
        'school_year' => 'required',
        'grades.*' => ['required','numeric','lt:2.50'],
        'grades1.*' => 'required|lt:2.50',
        'units.*' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'units1.*' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'term' => 'required',
        'term1' => 'required',
        'total.*' => 'nullable',
        'total1.*' => 'nullable',
        'gwa_1st' => 'required|lte:1.75',
        'gwa_2nd' => 'required|lte:1.75',
        'year_level' => 'required|string',
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        'award_applied' => 'required|string',
        'course_id' => 'required|string'

        'field_name' => [Rule::in([1.00, 1.25, 1.5, 2.75, 3.00])]
    ];
}
```

Obviously, replace `field_name` with the name of your `input` field. You will also need to include `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` at the top of your `AchieversAwardRequest`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a newbie in Laravel where should I add it in FormRequest or in Controller?

Comment: @SharmaeReyes Are you using a custom `FormRequest`?

Comment: yes it just my validations is in FormRequest

Comment: @SharmaeReyes I don't know what you mean. Please add your controller method to your question.

Comment: just add the rule to your form request.  You might need to make the array strings.

Comment: @Snapey The [In](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/In.php#L25) rule actually converts the supposed elements to strings anyway so isn’t necessary.